# How to find row change and lookup date based on product?

Tags: excel

I’m trying to think of a way of looking at groups of IDs and pull different dates based on two criteria.

```
ID      Date1       Date2       Product
101     1/1/2016    5/30/2016   Bond    
101     1/1/2016    5/30/2016   Swap    
101     1/1/2016    5/30/2016   Swap
201     2/28/2016   7/1/2016    Swap
201     2/28/2016   7/1/2016    Swap
201     2/28/2016   7/1/2016    Swap
```

If ColumnD is a Bond, fetch the corresponding Date1 and if it’s a Swap, fetch the corresponding Date2.  The thing is, I have to look for a change in the ID, because this is a pool and I want to do some lookups, or index/match, based on each pool.  Whenever the ID changes, I need to check the Bond or Swap, and pick the appropriate date.

The Bond is primary here, so if a Bond exists for a pool, use Date1 and if no Bond for the pool, use Date2.

Can someone give me a suggestion here?

Comment: Use VBA,  and go row by row down the ID column. Whenever you see a new value for the ID, check the product column to see if it is a Bond or a Swap.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, or I could use a pivot, but I was hoping to find a function only solution.

Answer (score 1):

@dev1998's answer seems to be on the right track, but it doesn't ensure that "Bond" is primary. So, if you have cases where Swap is listed before Bond, it would fail. I'm not sure if this ever happens within your particular data set, though.

So, let me start out my answer with some assumptions:

- *Pool* refers to all items that have the same ID.
- The table is sorted by ID.
- Within a pool, Swap could appear before Bond.
- Date1 may vary within a pool.
- Date2 may vary within a pool.
- If there is more than one Bond within a pool, use the most recent (greatest) Date1.
- If there is more than one Swap within a pool, use the most recent (greatest) Date2.

Given these assumptions, I would actually go with three columns of formulas, so you'd end up with something like this:

[image]

Here are the formulas:

- PrimaryProduct: `=IF(A2<>A1,D2,IF(E1="Bond","Bond",D2))` (for a given pool, this ensures that Bond takes precedence over Swap)
- Primary Date: `=IF(A2<>A1,IF(D2="Bond",B2,C2),IF(D2="Bond",IF(E1="Bond",MAX(B2,F1),B2),IF(E1="Bond",F1,MAX(C2,F1))))` (for a given pool, this determines the maximum date among all Bond entries if any exist, otherwise, it takes the maximum date among all Swap entries)
- IsLastItemInPool: `=A2<>A3` (simply determines if a given item is the last one in the pool -- this is for filtering purposes)

To perform your analysis, you should copy the formulas down then filter the table on `IsLastItemInPool = TRUE`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check to see if the bond was primary.  I up voted you to get this answer ahead of mine.

Comment: Thanks @dev1998, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "ID" is in cell A1. If so then put this in cell E3:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,IF(D3="Bond",B3,C3),"Same ID")
```

Copy the formula all the way down from E3 to the end of the data.

The formula will check to see if the ID is different from the ID in the row above it. Then it will see if you have a Bond or a Swap.

Comment: @ryguy72 you have a bunch of questions with multiple answers, and only a single one of them has an accepted answer. Please consider going through your questions, and marking as accepted those answers which solve your problems. If some are insufficient: don't hesitate to ask for clarification from the answerers. A question with unsatisfactory answers is not a good thing for Stack Overflow.